# Proving $2^n -1 = \sum_{i=0} ^{n-1} 2^i$ for all $n\geq 1$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm practicing proofs by induction, and equalities seem to be the toughest for me. Can somebody please help to prove that for all integers $n \geq 1$: 
$$
2^n -1 = \sum \limits _{i=0} ^{n-1} 2^i\;?
$$

Comment: What is $2^n+2^n-1$ when you simplify it?

Comment: Intuitively this simply says that $1\underbrace{00\ldots 00_2}_{n\text{ 0's}}-1_2=\underbrace{11\ldots 11_2}_{n\text{ 1's}}$ (in binary).

Comment: Please learn to type formulae using the LaTeX style.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq 1$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : \sum_{i=0} ^{n-1} 2^i=2^n-1.
$$
**Base case ($n=1$):** $S(1)$ says that $\sum_{i=0}^{1-1}2^i = 2^0=1=2^1-1$, and this is true.

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 1$ and assume that $S(k)$ is true where
$$
S(k) : \sum_{i=0} ^{k-1} 2^i=2^k-1.
$$
To be shown is that $S(k+1)$ follows where
$$
S(k+1) : \sum_{i=0} ^{k} 2^i=2^{k+1}-1
$$
Beginning with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i &= 2^k+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^i\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[0.5em]
&= 2^k+(2^k-1)\tag{by induction hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
&= 2\cdot 2^k-1\tag{simplify}\\[0.5em]
&=2^{k+1}-1,\tag{desired expression}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, thus completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Could you please explain what you did on the line with "(by defn. of Σ)"?

Comment: @RandomMath Consider this: $$\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i= \underbrace{2^k}_{\text{sum when evaluated at $i=k$}}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^i$$

Comment: Mmm - Im still struggling to understand what you are doing at the induction step. How you are getting to "(by defn. of Σ)" is what is confusing me. Because of this ∑i=0k2i=2k

Comment: @RandomMath I can't even really tell what you are writing there--you really do need to learn some $\rm\LaTeX$ so people can actually read your questions well. It seems like your real problem here lies in understanding $\Sigma$-notation. I'd recommend seeing [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/seq_induction/geometric-sequence-series/v/sigma-notation-sum) before trying to continue. My answer will make perfect sense after you watch that I believe.

Comment: @RandomMath $\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i=2^0+2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed/slightly rigourous proof:

We have to prove that the set $$S = \{k\in \mathbb{N} : 2^k -1 = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i \} = \mathbb{N}.$$
In order to do that, we prove that  $ S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \subset S$, so that we get $S = \mathbb{N}$.

**First part:** $S \subset \mathbb{N}$:

By definition of the set S, it is clear that $S \subset \mathbb{N}$, because $k \in S \Rightarrow k \in \mathbb{N}. \,\,\,\,\,\square$

**Second part:** $\mathbb{N} \subset S$.

We will show that $k \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow k \in S$.

To do that, we prove $1 \in S$, and $j \in S \Rightarrow j+1 \in S$.

- $1 \in S$:

$2^1 - 1 = 1$ and $1 \in \mathbb{N}$ leads to $1 \in S$

- $j \in S \Rightarrow j+1 \in S$

Our *hypothesis* is that $j \in S$, and we have to show that, if the hypothesis is true, then the conclusion is also true. Note that we are not showing that the hypothesis IS true, we are *only* showing that the hypothesis GUARANTEES the conclusion (this confused me a lot when i was learning induction).

Proceeding, this step is usually called the induction step:
Starting with $j \in S$, we have the (assumed true) proposition:
$$ 2^{j} - 1 = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}2^i$$

By definition of summation, we can write:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{j}2^i = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}2^i + 2^{j} $$

However, since we are assuming for the sake of argument that $ 2^{j} - 1 = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}2^i$ then we can substitute in $2^{j}- 1$ in the formula that we have just arrived at, leading to:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{j}2^i = (2^j -1)+ 2^{j}$$

Which we can simplify to give:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{j}2^i = 2(2^j) -1 = 2^{j+1} -1.$$

So we have shown that $ j \in S \Rightarrow j+1 \in S$.

Hence, if an element $b \in \mathbb{N}$, then $b \in \mathbb{s}.  \,\,\,\,\,\,$

This completes our proof. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: For $n=1$, the LHS is $2^1-1=1$, while the RHS is $\sum_{i=0}^0 2^i=0$, which are equal.

Step 2: Assume that $2^n-1=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$ holds, and try to use this fact to prove that $2^{n+1}-1=\sum_{i=0}^n2^i$.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove it for n=1.
$$2^1-1=1=2^0=\sum_{i=0}^{1}2^i$$
Now we suppose it valid for $n=k$

We prove it for $n=k+1$ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}2^i=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^i+1=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^i+2-1=2(\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^i+1)-1=2((2^k-1)+1)-1=2^{k+1}-1$$